# Split a string into its respective words

Tags: php

If I have a string which is like this

`~1~~2~~3~`

How do I get the numbers out using php?

Answer (score 5):

Using regex:

```
$string = '~1~~2~~3~';
preg_match_all('/~(\w+)~/', $string, $m);
print_r($m[1]);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try with:

```
$input  = '~1~~2~~3~';
$output = array();

foreach ( explode('~~', $input) as $val ) {
  $output[] = (int) trim($val, '~');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
preg_match_all('/([\d]+)/', $string, $match);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd match the numbers:

```
preg_match_all("/(\d+)/", $string, $numbers)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, just so that you have every variation under the sun at your disposal... :-)

```
$s = '~1~~2~~3~';
$a = preg_split('/~+/', $s, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

[run code](http://ideone.com/hMBcHN)